# Visual Studio 2017 and webpack issue

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-2017

I installed VS 2017 with a working dot net core solution. Prior to installation I was able to run webpack and it would transpile all of my ts, html, etc. into one single main-client.js file. After installation it no longer was packing the html files for my angular 2 app and my webpack was showing all of the js files in the output.

I then removed the code off of my machine and pulled a fresh version from my git repo. I ran webpack before starting VS 2017 and running the migrations for the dot net core app. The webpack worked correctly again. Then I opened VS 2017 and it is now failing. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

Same problem -- dotnetcore / aspnetcore / angular application broke webpack when run in Visual Studio 2017.

Preventing .ts compilation fixed this for me.  In the .csproj files first PropertyGroup add:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    . . . 
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then you'll need to delete all the .js and .js.map files in your ClientApp/app folder.

By default vs2017 autocompiles .ts file, producing .js and .js.map.  Presumably, webpack was finding the .js files and then not processing the template .html files.

Comment: Many thanks, you saved my day! I spent many hours trying to find out what was going on after upgrading my project to VS2017. In my case, besides the fact that .js files were now generated, the HMR was no more detecting my .ts modifications probably because of that. Adding the TypeScriptCompileBlocked in the csproj file solved the problem.